# updating database with ajax not working

Tags: ajax, database

i have little trouble with updating database by ajax , but i couldnt make it to work.
i dont know what im doing wrong.

here my php file (sendata.php)

```
  <?php
       if ( isset($_POST['register']) && $userid != 0) 
         {$register = $_POST['register'] ;

            $sql2 =$db->setQuery("INSERT INTO ....  ");
                   $db->query() ;
           }

   ?>
```

and here my javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#register').click(function() {

        $.ajax({

            url: "sendata.php",
            data: {
                age: $('#age').val()
            },
            type: 'POST',

            success: function(msg) {
                alert("Data has been saved succefully");
                $('#mydata').html("<b> age: </b>" + age);
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

what is heppening to me is when register button is clicked i get only the alert , that data is saved succefully but when i go to database and see  , there is no record at all there.
im doing something wrong ?

EDIT :

this my button

```
     <input type="submit" id="register" name="register" value="Save my Data" />
```

Comment: Díd you define variable weight anywhere? Díd you check if database connection is correct in your php function? What is your complete query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sendata.php checks to see if 'register' is set: `if ( isset($_POST['register']) ...)`  So you must SET the variable 'register' in your request (I fixed the code - see bold):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#register').click(function() {

        $.ajax({

            url: "sendata.php",
            data: {
                age: $('#age').val(),
                register: "register"
            },
            type: 'POST',

            success: function(msg) {
                alert(msg);
                $('#mydata').html("<b> age: </b>" + age);
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

sendata.php

```
if ( isset($_POST['register']) && $userid != 0) 
{
     $register = $_POST['register'] ;
     $sql2 =$db->setQuery("INSERT INTO ....  ");
     $db->query() ;
     echo "SUCCESS";
     exit(0);
 } 
 echo "FAILURE";
```

Comment: "register=something" ? what something  ?this register is submit button , so what can be something pls?

Comment: it saids FAILURE  the success message. but i have done `register : "register"` and i dont know what should be there as you mentioned by doing something

Comment: #register might be a submit button, but you are not submitting the form.  Ajax is an asynchronous request that runs in javascript before the form is submitted.  You are sending a request to "sendata.php" and you are setting all of the data in the data part of the ajax request.  However on sendata.php you are checking "isset($_POST["request"]).  If you don't set it then isset() will return false.  And you can set it to be anything, in my code snippet I put register : "register".

Comment: u mean i remove `isset($_POST["request"])` from php file ? i dont get really what u want say , anyway i tried by this `register : "register"` but didnt work . i edited my post and added my button html

Comment: I edited my code to make it more clear.  Copy the code above... I added 5 total lines.

Comment: here my sql `INSERT INTO people (age ) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['age']."') `

Comment: add `echo "$userid $_POST[request]";` before the if statement and tell me what alert you get on your page.  The sql query isn't even running if the success message is saying "FAILURE".  It may be the $userid==0.

Comment: i dont understand anything. first u was right , it was userid empty. i have removed this $userid checking from if statment and when i submit i dont get any alert . when i put this userid i get alert failure. so i understand that without userid cheking no alert comes no failure and no success its like that it stopped in if statment and dont want echo success

Comment: at this point, I'm guessing there is an error in your sql statement which causes an error in your sendata.php page which throws some 400 error to the ajax request which means the success function will not be called but rather the failure function... see my code above.

Comment: i think i know what uis the problem , `$userid` is undefined , and in sql there is this `$userid` also. and when i try to define the userid by adding some variables of joomla it didnt work . but i think u get tired with me , im thanking u so much

Comment: There was some parenthesis mismatch in my code, so I removed it.  Remember to mark this question answered as the initial problem was solved.  Good luck with the sql and undefined errors

Answer (score 0):

Javascript:

```
                    jQuery(document).ready(function($)
                    {
                    //prevent registering the event more than once 

                    //$('#register').off('click').on('click',(function(e) {
```

(1.) I would start with:

```
                    $('form').off('submit').on('submit',(function(e) {
```

or ..

```
                        $('input[type="submit"]').off('click').on('click',(function(e) {
```

then ..

```
                                $.ajax({
                                              //url to touch
                                            url: "sendata.php",
                                            data: {
                                                age: $('#age').val()
                                            },
                                            type: 'POST',
                                            //on fail
                                                        fail: function(data){
                                                         //regular javascript alert on error
                                                                    alert("Oppps! Data error");
                                                        },
                                            //on success
                                            success: function(data) {
                                                //regular javascript alert on success
                                                alert("Data has been saved succefully");

                                                //assuming this is a div with an id of mydata
                                                $('#mydata').html("<b> Age is: </b>" + data);
                                            }
                                        });

                                //prevents default action as we are not submiting the form but rather making use of AJAX to touch the php file
                                e.preventDefault();

                                });

                    });
```

sendata.php

```
                                <?
                $msg= '';

                    if (  isset( $_POST['age'] )  ) 
                    {
                        $age = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "age", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
                //echo $age;

                //around this check if the insertion is correct and that you can talk to the db
                //db handling, insertion, etc..
                                  // $sql2 =$db->setQuery("INSERT INTO ....  ");
                                  // $db->query();

                        //$msg .= "Epic Win! $age";
                        $msg .= "$age";
                    }
                    else $msg .= 'Error, no age provided :( ';
                        //we are returning the data so we need to echo it as an output here.
                    echo $msg;

                ?>
```